# 'identifier' uses undefined class

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class A;

int main()
{
    A<int> obj;
}

template <class T>
class A
{
public:
    A();
};

template <class T>
A<T> ::A()
{}
```

My compiler (`MS Visual Studio Update 4 Pro`) gives me the following error:

```
error C2079: 'obj' uses undefined class 'A<int>'
```

`MinGW` is also giving me an error of the same meaning.

What is the reason of it? The declaration of class `A <T>` is before the `main` function, so it should be known.

Comment: You have to *define* the class before you use it.

Comment: @juanchopanza calm down, I didn't know it before. Why `-1`? I think it's the right answer - therefore post is as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what it says: the template hasn't been defined at the point at which you try to use it. The definition, not just the declaration, must be available in order to instantiate the template.